# dpkg package corrupt in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

**dpkg package seems to be corrupt in Ubuntu 16.04**

Anything I try `install/update/upgrade/remove` gives the same error. These commands are not working

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-gnome:
 language-selector-gnome depends on language-selector-common (= 0.165.4); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-selector-common
 language-selector-gnome

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPORt.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5Wqm.png)

I am sorry if my question/problem lacks clarity. Please let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: From the terminal type: sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg -  This will reinstall dpkg likely from a better or updated source. You may also want to install the additional components if you have not yet: sudo apt-get install dpkg-cross dpkg-repack dpkg-sig dpkg-www gkdebconf alien - "Alien" will allow you to covert rpm and other packages to .deb files for install in your Ubuntu system.  The language suggestion below is also a smart choice to do before and if you need to do this which I suggested.

Comment: Hi, I  had tried doing this, but it gives the same error as the one explained in the question.

Comment: I suggest: sudo apt-get update then  sudo apt-get install --reinstall language-selector-common language-selector-gnome which will reinstall the language packages which seem to be presenting the problem.  Do so before anything else.  Only if  heynnema's suggestion of dpkg-reconfigure doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your suggestions! Unfortunately, none of these command work, and all of them give the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

Open **System Settings** and choose **Language Support**. It may tell you that the installation is incomplete, and wants to download language packs. OK this.

If that doesn't fix your problem with dpkg, then start Synaptic from the Dash, type **language-selector-gnome** into the search box. Right-click on the only found item and select **Mark for reinstall**. Do the same for **language-selector-common**. Then click the **apply** icon.

Let us know how this works. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Al. **Language Support** in **System Settings** shows that English is installed and doesn't give any other message. It shows me options to install or uninstall other languages like English(US), English(Aus) etc, but these options aren't highlighted like English is.

I then started Synaptic and did what you told me. However, even in that case I am getting this error:
`E: Internal Error, No file name for language-selector-gnome:amd64`

Comment: In Synaptic, hit the RELOAD icon, and then try again. Cheers, Al

Comment: If the Synaptic way doesn't fix your problem, go to terminal and try **sudo dpkg-reconfigure language-selector-common** or **sudo dpkg-reconfigure language-selector-gnome**. Keep me posted. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi Al, Synaptic still gives the same error even after reload.
I had tried running `dpkg-reconfigure` earlier and it gives the following error:
**/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: language-selector-common is broken or not fully installed** and
**/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: language-selector-gnome is broken or not fully installed**
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: OK, in terminal, type **sudo apt-get -f install**. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi Al, it still gives the same error: [link](http://imgur.com/58hjMv8)

Comment: OK, we'll use some brute force. Open Synaptic. Find each of the two language packages. Right-click on each one, and select **Mark for complete removal**. Click the **Apply** icon. Then go back and mark the same two as **Install**, and click the **Apply** icon. If for some reason the first step wants to deinstall a ton of stuff, stop. Cheers, Al

Comment: Synaptic says that this action will also, impact `ubuntu-desktop` & `ubuntu-standard` [link](http://imgur.com/a/1GS9F). Should I still go ahead? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, don't do it then. I'm at a loss what to suggest next. Maybe reinstall Ubuntu? If you do it right, and install it into the same partition where it currently resides, it'll ask to keep your current /home. Backup first. Anybody? Cheers, Al